# image disappears in browser on refreshing a react route with param.id

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

I am using html `<img>` for displaying images in react. But when a route url  with params ( i.e => `this.props.history.push('master/'+id)`) like `localhost:3000/master/1` is being refreshed, all the images in the browser disappear. I have tried googling this issue, but i haven't found what I need to change.

The image before the page with param url is being refreshed:

[image: image before]

The image after the page with param url is being refreshed:

[image: image after]

The code for image tag:

```
<Toolbar>
 <img src="./imgs/icon@32.png" alt="" height="32" className={classes.appBarIcon} />
  <Typography variant="h6" component="h1" color="inherit" noWrap>
                        {APP_NAME}
  </Typography>
   <div className={classes.grow} />
    <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
     <IconButton onClick={() => this.handleMenuClick("/me")}> 
       <Icon className={classes.menuIcon}>account_circle</Icon>
     </IconButton>
    </div>
   </Toolbar>
```

The code for url changes:

```
handleRowClick = (id) => {
    this.props.history.push('master/'+ id);
}
<TableBody className={classes.tblBody}>
 {this.props.data.slice(this.state.page * this.state.rowsPerPage, this.state.page * this.state.rowsPerPage + this.state.rowsPerPage).map(item => {
   return (
    <TableRow key={item.id} onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(this.props.path,item.id)} hover>
       <TableCell>{item.id}</TableCell> 
       <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
       <TableCell>{item.description}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    );})}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some code sample maybe ?

Comment: i have added the code sample. The param for the url is added after clicking a table row and the url changes. The image tag are still there in the browser when the url changes. But the problem is after refreshing that page.